# How to throttle tasks such that only one runs at a time and rest are ignored

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an object that listens to external events. Upon receiving an event, my object needs to execute a task (a *Runnable*). However, there is a restriction:

Once the task starts executing, I should not start other tasks (I can ignore them) until original task is finished and certain amount of time passed after that (throttling).

Here's suggested implementation using *semaphore*:

```
public class Sample {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;

    public Sample(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;    
    }

    public void tryRun() {
        if (semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
            try {
                executor.submit(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                doIt();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    executor.schedule(
                                        new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                semaphore.release();
                                            }
                                        },
                                        1, 
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                    );
                                } catch (Throwable t) {
                                    semaphore.release();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                semaphore.release();            
            }
        }
    }

    private void doIt() {
        // the exact task executing logic is here
    }
}
```

The code seems too verbose to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

P.S. Another restriction is that *ScheduledExecutorService* is the only interface I have to the external executor and I cannot start my own threads/executors within my object

Comment: I edited title but +1 - it's a clear well-defined question with clear research effort (expl of what you learned in Concurrency in Practice and what looks to be working code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a single thread.  You'll have to decide whether it's okay to queue up a lot of the other tasks.  If not, pass it your own `BlockingQueue` with capacity 1, I believe this will let at most one task queue up.  I'm thinking about how to get that down to zero.

[One way to create a single threaded executor with unbounded queue.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)

Note you will need to configure the TPE to discard rejected tasks via a [`DiscardPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html).

Answer (score 5):

+1 to @djechlin.  That's the right answer.  To add the implementation:

```
ExecutorService threadPool =
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
       new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

To go back to your question.

> Once the task starts executing, I should not start other tasks (I can ignore them) until original task is finished and certain amount of time passed after that (throttling).

This starts 1 and only 1 thread, uses a synchronous-queue and the `DiscardPolicy` which will discard any tasks unless the thread is waiting to run it.  If the single thread is working then any tasks submitted to the pool will be rejected and sent to the rejection policy.  In your case you want to just discard them.

If you really want to *queue* the tasks if the working thread is busy, then you should use a bounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead.  Maybe with a rejection policy that blocks the caller when the queue is full.

Something like the following:

```
ExecutorService threadPool =
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10), new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
         public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
           // this will block the caller until the queue has space
           executor.getQueue().add(r);
         }
      });
```

Comment: Although I can't say I understand how it works yet, still reading on it - I'd suggest you explain how it works / solves the problem int he answer.